# Spark starting job with all workers, but at some point using only 1 executor in a single worker when doing count()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an DF which is partitioned, and relatively small.
I try to do a simple count().
At starts all workers and executors participating at the task, but at some point of the job, only 1 worker and 1 core is working. Even though the data is distributed in a balanced way among the workers.

I have tried coalesce to 1 and also repartition to 2*number of cores, still no effect - no matter what kind of action I do on this DF, it always starts with all workers and keep working only on a single 1.

I'd appreciate if anyone has any idea what could be wrong.

Information on the DF:

```
Total Count: 
13065

Partitions: 
+--------------------+-----+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|                   9| 5557|
|                  10|   62|
|                  11|  167|
|                   0|  128|
|                   1|   83|
|                   2|  110|
|                   3|  129|
|                   4|  131|
|                   5|   78|
|                   6| 6429|
|                   7|   39|
|                   8|  152|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Screenshots from application master:

DAG:

[image: dag]

event timeline:
[image: event timeline]

tasks:
[image: tasks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task always takes place on a single executor: it never gets chopped up into pieces and distributed since it is the most atomic bit of work a Spark executor does.

By looking at the image with the table of tasks we see 12 tasks (are these all the tasks in your stage or are there more?): most of them take <1s but then there is one that takes 4.6min.

Interesting observation indeed! It makes sense that if you have a task that takes MUCH longer than all of the other tasks that you can end up with with a single executor having to calculate alone at the end.

So actually your problem is more of a data skew question: why does this single task take so much longer than the other ones? To answer this, we don't have enough information out of your question. I would start looking at the following:

- As you can see in the screenshot of your stage, your stage reads from a shuffledRowRDD. So that means it is partitioned by something. By what is it partitioned? How many shuffled partitions does it read? What is the value of your `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configuration?
- In the task table, you can see that you have a GC time of 1s (WAY larger than for the other tasks). Are you counting large objects? Is it possible that the difference in size of your objects can be really big?

Hope this helps you in figuring this one out!